# AS3 Libraries: Am I missing FileStream?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, filestream

I think I'm missing some classes in my library.
If I type in 'import fil', FD4 autocompletes to only this:

```
import flash.net.FileFilter
import flash.net.FileReference
import flash.net.FileReferenceList
```

I saw people using FileStream and wondered why I don't have this class available.
Do you guys know why this happens and how I can obtain the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileStream is only available when targeting AIR 1.0+.